# JS Como autopreencher um input com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá

Preciso fazer um botão que ao clicar ele preenche de forma automática os campos de input.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="botao">Auto</button>
<input type="text" id="nome">
<input type="text" id="sobrenome">
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var nome = "Joãozinho";
   var sobrenome = "Fulano";

   $("#botao").click(function(){
      $("#nome").val(nome);
      $("#sobrenome").val(sobrenome);
   });
});
```

Mas ao clicar no button nada ocorre, o está errado no código?

Comment: O código funciona. Confirme se tem o jquery corretamente adicionado ao à página.

Comment: Realmente faltou jquery, muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codigo está correto, veja funcionando aqui

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var nome = "Joãozinho";
   var sobrenome = "Fulano";

   $("#botao").click(function(){
      $("#nome").val(nome);
      $("#sobrenome").val(sobrenome);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="botao">Auto</button>
<input type="text" id="nome">
<input type="text" id="sobrenome">
```